# You've uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle with an activity, object alias, service, or broadcast receiver with an intent filter?

Tags: android

I'm trying to download the application set, I get the following error.

You've uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle with an activity, object alias, service, or broadcast receiver with an intent filter, but no android:exported property set. This file cannot be installed on a device running Android 12 or higher. To learn more, go to developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported.

**MY ANDROIDMANIFEST:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gallery.photosgallery.videogallery.google">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>


<application
    android:name="com.gallery.photosgallery.videogallery.google.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Gallery3">
    <activity 
android:name="com.gallery.photosgallery.videogallery.google.Activity.ViewVideoActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gallery3.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        
 android:name="com.gallery.photosgallery.videogallery.google.Activity.ViewVideoAlbumActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gallery3.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.gallery.photosgallery.videogallery.google.Activity.EditActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gallery3.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        
 android:name="com.gallery.photosgallery.videogallery.google.Activity.ViewImageActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gallery3.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        
android:name="com.gallery.photosgallery.videogallery.google.Activity.ViewAlbumActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gallery3.NoActionBar" />

    <service android:name="com.gallery.photosgallery.videogallery.google.Service.GetFileList"
        android:exported="true"
        />

    <activity
        android:name="com.gallery.photosgallery.videogallery.google.Activity.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gallery3.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check  your merged manifest; your problem may be coming from an out of date library.

Comment: Tell me how to do it?

Comment: Open your manifest in Android Studio, and look in the "Merged Manifest" sub-tab.

Comment: How can I determine which library is outdated?

Comment: If you find a component with an `<intent-filter>` that lacks `android:exported`, look at the fully-qualified class name of the component. Hopefully, something about its package will give you a clue of where the component comes from.